# Common Lisp Execute expression as parameter in macro

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lisp-macros

So using common lisp, I want to be able to do something of the sorts of:

```
(defmacro foo (count &rest someExpression)
    `(do
        ((,count 0 (+ ,count 1)))
        ((= ,count 5) T)
        `(eval ,someExpression)
    )
)
(foo (print 1) temp)
```

With the result of it printing 1 5 times. I do not want to simply call (print 1) directly, but by passing the expression through a macro parameter and calling it via the macro. In other words, the macro foo should handle any expression(s) as input and run it. This case does not seem to work.

Edited to clarify an explicit script and intended function.

Comment: What is `someExpression` that "_does not seem to work?_" [MCVE]. Why is `someExpression` wrapped in parentheses when the macro is expanded? Consider `someExpression` as `(+ 1 2 3)`: `(eval ((+ 1 2 3)))` is probably not the desired expansion.

Comment: @adabsurdum I have edited the question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: You need to explain why you'd want to use a macro for this: what code transformation are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `(print 1)` is a valid Lisp form. `((print 1))`, `(((print 1)))`, ... `(((((print 1)))))` are not valid Lisp forms.

Comment: @tfb I want to use a macro because I want to use a macro. I am not sure what you are asking as the question does not need that to be answered, especially if it is hypothetical. What I am trying to achieve as I have explicitly said is, in this case to simply print 1 as output. In general, execute what is sent as the parameter of foo, as I have also stated.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I am getting a (print 1) is not a valid function name when doing eval.

Comment: @JustAFellowCoder: that's what I' saying. You are not evaluating `(print 1)`. You are evaluating something else. Take a look at my prior comment for a hint.

Comment: @RainerJoswig So I am evaluating ((print 1)) instead of (print 1). How do I form (print 1) from ((print 1))?

Comment: Best by not creating `((print))` in the first place. Then you don't need to remove anything.

Comment: @RainerJoswig I am not saying what is best. What is best would be using a function instead of a macro most likely. But in this specific case, I want to use a macro for this and be given something like ((print 1)).

Comment: You are not given `((print 1))`. You are given `(print 1)`. Your macro adds the extra parentheses. It puts the form into a list. Why?

Comment: You need to learn what macros are useful for, which is not this.  And also why not to use `eval`. But `(defmacro serves-no-possible-useful-purpose (form) form)`: the code transformation you want is the identity transformation.

Comment: @RainerJoswig where? Changing `(eval (,someExpression)) to (eval ,someExpression) still gives a not a valid function error.

Comment: works for me actually

Comment: `(defmacro foo (someExpression) `(eval ,someExpression))`  -> `FOO`. `(foo (print 1))`-> `1 1`

Comment: Then next you can try to see the difference of: `(defmacro foo (someExpression) `(eval ',someExpression))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your recent version, which is at least a reasonable candidate for a macro unlike the older one:

```
(defmacro foo (someExpression count-var)
  `(do ((,count-var 0 (+ ,count 1)))
       ((= ,count-var 5) T)
     `(eval (,someExpression))))
```

Well what is the expansion of `(foo (print 1) c)`?

```
(foo (print 1) x)
 -> (do ((x 0 (+ x 1))) ((= x 5) t)
      `(eval (,someexpression)))
```

Well, that's a disaster: what is that nested backquote doing?  Let's just remove it:

```
(defmacro foo (someExpression count-var)
  `(do ((,count-var 0 (+ ,count 1)))
       ((= ,count-var 5) T)
     (eval (,someExpression))))
```

```
(foo (print 1) x)
 -> (do ((x 0 (+ x 1))) ((= x 5) t)
      (eval ((print 1))))
```

That's less disastrous, but the `eval` form is entirely bogus.  We can make that 'work' by changing it to be at least syntactically legal:

```
(defmacro foo (someExpression count)
  `(do ((,count 0 (+ ,count 1)))
       ((= ,count 5) T)
     (eval ,someExpression)))
```

And now

```
(foo (print 1) x)
 -> (do ((x 0 (+ x 1))) ((= x 5) t)
      (eval (print 1)))
```

And this will 'work' but it will work purely by coincidence: because `(print 1)` returns `1` and the value of `1` is `1`.

```
(foo (print 'foo) x)
  -> (do ((x 0 (+ x 1))) ((= x 5) t)
       (eval (print 'foo)))
```

and that's a run-time error.

But ... why are you using `eval`?  `eval` is a terrible, terrible solution to almost any problem you can think of, unless the solution to the problem is called 'code injection attack', and in this case it's not just terrible: it's wrong.  So we just remove it.

```
(defmacro foo (someExpression count)
  `(do ((,count 0 (+ ,count 1)))
       ((= ,count 5) T)
     ,someExpression))
```

And now

```
(foo (print 'foo) x)
 -> (do ((x 0 (+ x 1))) ((= x 5) t)
      (print 'foo))
```

Which looks like the code transformation we want.  So, finally:

```
> (foo (print 'foo) x)

foo 
foo 
foo 
foo 
foo 
t
```

Which is, finally, fine.  And this works:

```
> (foo (print x) x)

0 
1 
2 
3 
4 
t
```

---

As with yet another edit to the question it probably is more useful to put the variable name first and allow a bunch of expressions:

```
(defmacro foo (count-var &body forms)
  `(do ((,count-var 0 (+ ,count-var 1)))
       ((= ,count-var 5))
     ,@forms))
```

This will now allow multiple expressions in the body.  And we could go further: we could allow it to specify the number of iterations and the return value`:

```
(defmacro foo ((count-var &optional (count 1) (value 'nil)) &body forms)
  `(do ((,count-var 0 (1+ ,count-var)))
       ((= ,count-var ,count) ,value)
     ,@forms))
```

And now

```
> (foo (x 2)
    (print x)
    (print (* x 2)))

0 
0 
1 
2
nil
```

Well, the name of this macro is `dotimes` of course.

Comment: Thank you. This clarified everything in perfect detail. As it was, the parentheses were breaking it as well as missing ,@ in the case of &rest and the eval function was useless.